# Exclude a class when it is inside an element with the same class using jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am finding all `.normalize` and for each, I find the `.normalize-item` within it. But one of them has another `.normalize` inside. I need to exclude that `.normalize` inside `.normalize`, because I want just find the `.normalize-item` of this `.normalize`.

```js
var normalize = $(".normalize");
var colors = ["red", "blue"];
var higherHeight = 0;

normalize.each((colorIndex, el) => {
    var panels = $(el).find(".normalize-item");
    panels.css("height", "auto");

    panels.each((i, el) => {
        $(el).css({
            "border": "4px solid",
            "border-color": colors[colorIndex]
        });
        higherHeight = higherHeight < $(el).height() ? $(el).height() : higherHeight;
    });
    panels.css("height", higherHeight);
});
```

```css
.normalize {
    float: left;
}

span {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}

.normalize-item {
    float: left;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="normalize">
    <div class="normalize-item">
        <span> Item 1.1 <br><br><br><br></span>
    </div>
    <div class="normalize-item">
        <span>
      Item 1.2
    </span>
        <div class="normalize">
            <div class="normalize-item">
                <span> Item 2.1 </span>
            </div>
            <div class="normalize-item">
                <span> Item 2.2 </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="normalize-item">
        <span> Item 1.3 </span>
    </div>
    <div class="normalize-item">
        <span> Item 1.4 </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So you need to exclude 2.1 and 2.2?

Comment: I need to exclude the entire `.normalize` inside the first `.normalize`

Comment: `var normalize = $(".normalize").first();` ?

Comment: No, because i need to get de second normalize. I need to get the two separate `.normalize`

Comment: How about this: `var normalize = $(".normalize:not(div > .normalize)");`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/qw1k9qva/5/

Comment: Thank you @Hackerman but i found the solution, i wrote the answer, see there.

Answer (score 1):

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](https://jsfiddle.net/qw1k9qva/4/)***

Just filter the normalize set before iterating it

```
normalize.filter((_,el) => {
    //only return true when there are no class=normalize parents
    return $(el).parents('.normalize').length == 0
}).each...
```

Comment: This code is not that i need, but the filter help me to fix my code. Thank you.
Here my fixed code: https://jsfiddle.net/jmlavoier/qw1k9qva/7/

Comment: @JmLavoier - Post your code as an answer, and explain the difference. That way you can accept the exact solution and not just a stepping stone :)

Answer (score -1):

The solution about my issue, i use the `filter` to in each `.normalize` to exclude the all `.normalize-item` that are inside another `.normalize`.

I count how much `.normalize` parents there are and attributing into `countNormalizeParent`. And after i use to filter the `.normalize-item`.

```js
var normalize = $(".normalize");
var colors = ["red", "blue"];

normalize.each((colorIndex, el) => {
 var higherHeight = 0;
 var countNormalizeParent = $(el).parents(".normalize").length;
    var panelsFiltered = $(el).find(".normalize-item").filter((_,el) => {
        return $(el).parents('.normalize').length == countNormalizeParent + 1;
    });
    
    panelsFiltered.css("height", "auto");
    
    panelsFiltered.each((i, el) => {
        $(el).css({
            "border": "4px solid",
            "border-color": colors[colorIndex]
        });
        higherHeight = higherHeight < $(el).height() ? $(el).height() : higherHeight;
    });
    panelsFiltered.css("height", higherHeight);
});
```

```css
.normalize {
    float: left;
}

span {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}

.normalize-item {
    float: left;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="normalize">
    <div class="normalize-item">
        <span> Item 1.1 <br><br><br><br></span>
    </div>
    <div class="normalize-item">
        <span>
      Item 1.2
    </span>
        <div class="normalize">
            <div class="normalize-item">
                <span> Item 2.1 </span>
            </div>
            <div class="normalize-item">
                <span> Item 2.2 </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="normalize-item">
        <span> Item 1.3 </span>
    </div>
    <div class="normalize-item">
        <span> Item 1.4 </span>
    </div>
</div>
```